# Install fonts into a certain directory (as non-root)

Tags: fonts, texmf

I am trying to install MinionPro (using [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro)) into my home directory. What I usually do is to install packages is to put the .sty and other files into some directory, say `~/latexstyles`, and then do

```
export TEXINPUTS=$HOME/latexstyles//:.:
```

so latex will pick up all the files. The advantage is that I can copy the contents of this directory to different systems that often have wildly different latex versions, and it still works. However, this scheme doesn't work with fonts. The proper way to do this seems to do

```
sudo updmap --enable Map=MinionPro     # or edit updmap.cfg or /etc/texmf/updmap.d
sudo updmap
```

and then updmap modifies some system-wide configuration files. How do I translate this to an installation in the home directory?

I'd like to have a result that I can just copy to another system, since I can't run the FontPro scripts on my target system (can't install the dependencies of FontPro there). I tried setting

```
TEXMF=$HOME/latexstyles
```

(and variations), but then updmap does nothing, and pdflatex doesn't run anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run updmap you will have to load the map-file in the document with
`\pdfmapfile{=MinionPro.map}`.

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately, because pdflatex wont find MinionPro.map. Also I think there is some code in the .sty file that is neccessary, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post what I came up to until now. This works on both systems I have (a modern Ubuntu and a couple-years-old Red Hat at work, with corresponding Latex. I don't know exactly which versions/distributions, right now). Currently, there is still a problem with math, so it only works with text.

I used `updmap` with custom paths, and then set environment variables so `pfdlatex` would pick up the paths.

1. Install MinionPro according to the FontPro README. Use as installation path e.g. `$HOME/latexstyles/adobefonts`

```
./scripts/install ~/latexstyles/adobefonts
```

2. If needed, install fontaxes and MnSymbol to somewhere on your TeX path, can be the same directory as above. (MnSymbol was neccessary for compiling the text-only .tex on the RedHat computer, I guess it is neccessary for math in general.)

3. Create the following files, and edit `BASE`. You might have to comment out the line regarding MnSymbol if you are installing it here.

install.sh

```
BASE=$HOME/latexstyles/adobefonts
echo "Map MinionPro.map" >> $BASE/updmap.cfg 
#echo "MixedMap MnSymbol.map" >> $BASE/updmap.cfg 

mkdir -p $BASE/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap $BASE/fonts/map/dvips/updmap $BASE/fonts/map/dvipdfm/updmap 

export TEXFONTMAPS="$BASE/fonts/map//:$TEXFONTMAPS"
updmap --cnffile=$BASE/updmap.cfg --pdftexoutputdir=$BASE/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap --dvipsoutputdir=$BASE/fonts/map/dvips/updmap --dvipdfmoutputdir=$BASE/fonts/map/dvipdfm/updmap --copy

# must be set after updmap, otherwise it won't work
export TEXINPUTS="$BASE//:$TEXINPUTS"
```

setup.sh

```
BASE=$HOME/latexstyles/adobefonts
export TEXFONTMAPS="$BASE/fonts/map//:$TEXFONTMAPS"
export TEXINPUTS="$BASE//:$TEXINPUTS"
export ENCFONTS="$BASE/fonts//:$ENCFONTS"
export TFMFONTS="$BASE/fonts//:$TFMFONTS"
export T1FONTS="$BASE/fonts//:$T1FONTS"
export VFFONTS="$BASE/fonts//:$VFFONTS"
```

4. Call `bash install.sh` once. You may now copy around the adobefonts directory if needed. Before compiling something, call `source setup.sh`.

I haven't tested this extensively, but it works for a minimal document, and since it is self-contained it should not damage anything.

Minimal Document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}

\section{This is MinionPro}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat 
cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I should say that this is not completely satisfactory, as it is missing some glyphs (e.g. bullet points) and math support. Once I figure it out, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Edit: I was missing the VFFONTS variable, bullet points and basic math works now.